# ldd:FATAL: Unresolved symbol "getopt_long" called from Executable - using compiled binaries for QNX on arm. Why?

Tags: compiling, arm, qnx

The *Blackberry Playbook* has formally reached [EOL](http://ca.blackberry.com/support/business/software-support-life-cycle.html)(april 2014), but I've installed [*BGShell*](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/87835/?lang=en&countrycode=US), [*BGSSH-SCP-SFTP*](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/19204890/?lang=en&countrycode=US), and [*Term48*](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/26272878/?lang=en&countrycode=US) on it. So I have some *ksh*-like shell it seems with things like GNU `awk` 3.1.5, `sed` 4.1.5, `grep` and `python`, with **some** other *coreutils* elements (but no `tr`) etc. I'm *not root*. Basically I can write in the `Downloads` directory or in the *$HOME* dir created by the shell apps (`/accounts/1000/appdata/com.BGShell..blabla/data` for instance) and I can't execute everything but I can generally run a script within the aforementioned constraints. The reason I'm interested is because this is [*QNX*](http://www.qnx.com/products/neutrino-rtos/neutrino-rtos.html#overview) on [cortex-A9](http://www.arm.com/markets/mobile/15425.php).:

```
QNX localhost 6.6.0 2014/03/19-01:28:41EDT OMAP4430_ES2.2_HS_Winchester_Rev:07 armle
```

---

So I compiled some binaries by trying to leverage an [old project](https://github.com/mordak/playbook-dev-tools)<sup>1</sup>. Many things need be changed for this to work but it is set up and is able to compile most targets(including `gcc` and `coreutils-8.13`)<sup>2</sup>. To *summarize*, I compiled using many different variations of configure flags and older versions of some dev tools to avoid some errors. I've settled for something like:

```
CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -marm -fno-strict-aliasing -mtune=cortex-a9 -O2 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -mlittle-endian"
AUTOMAKE=automake-1.11: AUTOCONF=: AUTOHEADER=: AUTORECONF=: ACLOCAL=aclocal-1.11: MAKEINFO=makeinfo-4.13a
```

with the `arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0eabi-gcc` cross-compiler linked from the *10.3 SDK* which sits inside the *momentics* IDE. The resulting binaries look like this:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[md5/uuid]=41442b23fecda2d1d7cc5d2c68432a33, not stripped
```

---

But every one of them errors on the tablet with this message:

```
ldd:FATAL: Unresolved symbol "getopt_long" called from Executable
```

As I recompiled many times using different flags and always get that message, I'm thinking I maybe mislinked some other things than the compiler in the build scripts as it was geared for a prior sdk... (this is beyond my expertise but maybe something about garbage collecting i.e. `collect`?). Or is it the exotic configuration on the target platform?

A million things could have gone wrong here because of the setup(and inexperience) but I'm looking for some clues so is there any specific thing I should understand from such an error and how can I backtrack the problem generally?

---

<sup>1. In summary it is a bunch of scripts to *fetch*, *patch*, *compile*, *install* to some dir then *bundle* that dir to one zip file then spawn a cute *ruby webrick* server and you use the tablet to download the script and the archive from it(I don't use it for the archive at 250mb, I just use some web file host and the browser).</sup>

<sup>2. I've removed the *ruby*, *file*, and *ruby* targets from the top level build configuration.</sup>

Comment: looks like you are not the only one: http://community.qnx.com/sf/go/projects.core_os/discussion.newcode.topc7360   and this one 
  http://qdn.qnx.com/support/knowledgebase.html?id=50130000000maSD *A getopt_long implemetation is available on Foundry27. For example: /utils/d/diff/lib/getopt1.c*

Comment: @Emmanuel Your comment was quite insightful, thank you. Actually it's possible the binaries I compiled were BB10 compatible. But the tablet OS is not BB10, although they share some common elements. I need to use the tablet OS sdk and the link from the old project didn't lead to that... we'll see what happens now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about confusing two different SDK<sup>1</sup>. *getopt_long* [exists](http://community.qnx.com/sf/discussion/do/listPosts/projects.core_os/discussion.newcode.topc7360?_pagenum=6) on *QNX6.6*. But the `libc` version on the *Playbook* [doesn't have that](http://community.qnx.com/sf/discussion/do/listPosts/projects.core_os/discussion.newcode.topc7360?_pagenum=7) as it has an earlier version of */proc*. The error would have never happened if I had installed the [*Playbook OS Native SDK v2.1.0*](http://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/native/download/) instead of blindly following the [link](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/download/) in the project, which will install the *Native SDK v10.3* with the 2.1 **IDE** for *BB10*. The project's information is clear but the link doesn't link to the proper SDK. So what I ended up with were most likely binaries made to run on the BB10 but on a device which doesn't exactly have the same infrastructure. Interestingly something like `grep` would work but refused to answer to `--version` i.e. a long option when compiled with the BB SDK...

---

But with the proper SDK there is no issue. Most targets have been recompiled<sup>2</sup>. This is all happening on *Arch Linux x84_64* where [*multilib*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch64_FAQ#Multilib_repository) repositories have been enabled(and many *lib32-* packages pulled). This is the `build.sh` configuration block I have used for `gcc`<sup>3</sup>:

```
CONFIGURE_CMD="$EXECDIR/gcc/configure
           --host=$PBHOSTARCH 
           --build=$PBBUILDARCH 
           --target=$PBTARGETARCH 
           --srcdir=$EXECDIR/gcc 
           --with-as=ntoarm-as 
           --with-ld=ntoarm-ld 
           --with-sysroot=$BBTOOLS/target/qnx6/ 
           --disable-werror 
           --prefix=$DESTDIR 
           --exec-prefix=$DESTDIR 
           --enable-cheaders=c 
           --enable-languages=c 
           --enable-threads=posix 
           --disable-nls
           --disable-libssp 
           --disable-tls 
           --disable-libstdcxx-pch
           --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls
           --enable-libmudflap 
           --enable-__cxa_atexit 
           --with-gxx-include-dir=$BBTOOLS/target/qnx6/usr/include 
           --enable-shared
           --disable-subdir-texinfo
           --enable-cross-compile
           --enable-shared
           CC=$PBTARGETARCH-gcc
           CFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -marm -fno-strict-aliasing -mtune=cortex-a9 -O2 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -mlittle-endian'
           LDFLAGS='-Wl,-s '
           MAKEOPTS="-j5"
           AUTOMAKE=automake-1.11: AUTOCONF=: AUTOHEADER=: AUTORECONF=: ACLOCAL=aclocal-1.11: MAKEINFO=makeinfo-4.13a
```

---

Both `coreutils` and `gcc` work and I have aliased `ls` and `grep` with the `--color` option:

[image]

At last a functional shell with `tr`on my *Playbook*, which offers a rare insight into [*QNX*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNX)!

---

<sup>1. Thanks to *Ryan Mansfield* @Foundry27 for the heads up and to *@Emmanuel* for the info!</sup>

<sup>2. Excluded targets: `file`, `man`, `ruby`, `findutils`. The resulting archive was 80Mib and the `ruby` *webrick* server was used to deploy as intended.</sup>

<sup>3. ...for both `gcc` and `coreutils` actually(adding to the defaults in the latter case). It is not clear that all options are required or even recommended. Every target can be built individually by launching the `build.sh` script in the appropriate `bootstrap/target` directory i.e. `bootstrap/gcc/build.sh`. The build environment(`bbndk-env.sh`) must have been sourced once by the global top build.sh script using the `-b` option i.e. `build.sh -b /path/to/bbndk-2.10`. Sources are fetched to the `work/target` directories where they're built. If a build succeeds and no options is given(see `lib.sh` in the project root dir), it gets added to the `pbhome` directory structure which will be zipped into an archive(which will be deployed to your $HOME dir on the device running *BGShell*). Also note the reference to *Darwin* in `lib.sh` which I changed to  *x86_64* in my case. Otherwise nothing has been altered from the original project configuration i.e. `arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.5.0eabi`(as opposed to using the 8.0.0 version with the BB10.3 SDK like in the Q.). So it is very easy to compile once we weed out the few problematic targets.</sup>

Comment: I was able to compile _bash-4.3_, _zsh-5.0.5_ and _links_ directly on the tablet with that `gcc`...